# data$column returning null in a user-defined function

Tags: r, datacolumn

I'm new at  R (and stackoverflow , too), so please forgive any possible stupidity!

I wrote a function

```
     getvariance <-function(data, column)
```

that returns the variance of values in `column` in `data`

In the function I wrote

```
    mydata = read.csv(data)
    for i=1:datasize {
      x=(mydata$column)[i]
      //compute variance of x
    }
```

When I call

```
     getvariance("randomnumbers.csv", X1)
```

x is returned as a column of null values.

However, when I simply write

```
     x=(mydata$X1[i])
```

it prints the full column with numerical values.

Can anyone help me understand why `mydata$column[i]` doesn't work when column's a parameter of a function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access `data$column` instead of `data$X1`.

```
data <- data.frame(X1=1:3)
data$X1
## [1] 1 2 3
data$column
## NULL
```

Instead try to actually access the column with the name X1 as follows:

```
fct <- function(data, column){
  data[,column]
}
fct(data, "X1")
## [1] 1 2 3
```